# Why would running the same annotate function in ggplot2 work for others but throw an error for me (aesthetic length)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, version, annotate

I created a graph using ggplot2 that worked originally. Without changing anything, it stopped working for me, throwing the error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label". However, I have co-workers run my code on their systems, and it works perfectly. What could cause this? We all have almost the same version or R, RStudio, ggplot2, and tidyverse installed.

I have tried calling the ggplot2 library before and after calling the tidyverse library, to see if maybe it was a version mis-match. I uninstalled all of my packages and re-installed them. I uninstalled R and re-installed R. It never works for me, and always works for them.

I have ggplot2 version 3.2.0 and they have ggplot2 version 3.1.1. The https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases site says the 3.2.0 version "fixed" a problem that maybe had enabled co-workers with 3.1.1 to run the code even though it wasn't supposed to run; that implies there is something in my code that is incorrect that somehow previous 3.1.1 versions could run accidentally. Here's the line in the 3.2.0 release version that seemed relevant:

> "In some cases, ggplot2 now produces a warning or **an error for code that previously produced plot output**. In all these cases, the previous plot output was accidental, and the plotting code uses the ggplot2 API in a way that would lead to undefined behavior. **Examples include... annotations across multiple facets (#3305)**...")

So either this is a problem with my software or package settings or my code is wrong. Any thoughts?

These are all the libraries I call:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
library(extrafont)
```

This is what the console prints when I run library(tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
  method         from 
  [.quosures     rlang
  c.quosures     rlang
  print.quosures rlang
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.2.0       v purrr   0.3.2  
v tibble  2.1.1       v dplyr   0.8.0.1
v tidyr   0.8.3       v stringr 1.4.0  
v readr   1.3.1       v forcats 0.4.0  
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ 
tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Here is the whole table that I am making into a graph:

```
  Component_ProgramItem    task        ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18    date.type  task.date
1 Citywide Programs        Original    2019-12-31                  end        2012-08-30
2 Neighborhood Parks       Original    2016-01-27                  end        2013-03-31
3 Waterfront Parks         Original    2019-12-31                  end        2015-02-28
4 Neighborhood Parks       Updated     2016-01-27                  end        2016-01-27
5 Citywide Programs        Updated     2019-12-31                  end 2020-03-31
6 Waterfront Parks         Updated     2019-12-31                  end 2020-04-30
7 Citywide Programs        Original    2019-12-31                  start      2008-08-28
8 Neighborhood Parks       Original    2016-01-27                  start      2008-08-28
9 Waterfront Parks         Original    2019-12-31                  start        2008-08-28
10 Citywide Programs       Updated     2019-12-31                  start        2012-08-30
11 Neighborhood Parks      Updated     2016-01-27                  start        2013-03-31
12 Waterfront Parks        Updated     2019-12-31                  start        2015-02-28
```

Here is the code I use to make it into a graph:

```
#6 Create ggplot schedule
#order of "label=c("label name...", Label name 2...", ) is alphabetical
ggplot(csnp2008.sched.long, aes(x=task, y=task.date, colour=task)) + 
  geom_line(size=70, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#fadd9d", "#ffc000")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#fadd9d", "#ffc000")) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  scale_y_date(breaks = "1 year", date_minor_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y") +
  #guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL, reverse=TRUE)) +
  geom_hline(data = csnp2008.sched.long, aes(yintercept=ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18), 
             color = "#7f7f7f", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", x="task", y=as.Date("2008-10-30"),
          label=c("Citywide Programs",
                   "Neighborhood Parks",
                  "Waterfront Parks"),
          size = 3.75, hjust = "left", family = "Segoe UI Semilight") +
  #facet_grid(Component~., switch = "y", labeller = labeller(Component = label_wrap_gen(10))) + 
  facet_grid(Component_ProgramItem~., switch = "y", scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme_gantt() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size = 9, 
                        family = "Segoe UI Semilight"),
                        axis.line.x = element_line(color= "#e7e5e6"),
                        axis.ticks.x = element_line (color = "#7f7f7f"),
                        axis.title=element_blank(),
                        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                        strip.text = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()
```

It won't run this section of code for me, throwing the error after the annotate function: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label". However, it runs perfectly for everyone else and returns the right graph for them with no error messages.

Is this a software problem? Or a code problem?

P.S. I won't attach an image of the final graph because that's not really relevant I don't think. But if you need it, I can.

P.P.S here is the code to re-create:

```r
df2 <- structure(
                list(
                    Component_ProgramItem = c("Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs", "Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks"), 
                    task = c("Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule"),
                    ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18 = c("2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31"),
                    data.type = c("end", "end", "start", "start","end", "end", "start", "start","end", "end", "start", "start"),
                    task.date = c("2012-08-30","2020-03-31","2008-08-28","2012-08-30","2013-03-31","2016-01-27","2008-08-28","2013-03-31","2015-02-28","2020-04-30","2008-08-28","2015-02-28")), 
                    .Names = c("Component_ProgramItem", "task", "ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18", "data.type", "task.date"), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 12L), 
                    class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A tip for your next question: indent code and data by 4 spaces. Saves you all those `br` tags and me editing them :)

Comment: Your example data and code do not match up. There is no variable `task` in the data and variable `Task.Date` is lower-case in the code.

Comment: thank you @neilfws! I didn't know how to do that. Much improved. Also, I re-named the columns as they are in the data... I thought shorthand would be user-friendly because the code isn't the problem (maybe), but I see now that was confusing. Anything else I can improve?

Comment: @neilfws I also made the data real if that's helpful, although somehow can't make that last column align quite right.

Comment: You can provide us with the data sample using the `dput()` function

Comment: @SimonWoodward thank you. That 12-row table is actually the entire data frame. Do you still need me to use dput() - and if so, could you explain how in StackOverflow? This data is not accessible anywhere but my hardware. I don't see anything about that on StackOverflow help links.

Comment: do `dput(yourdataframe)` and then copy the output to here. Are you date columns Date format? I don't think as.Date("2008-10-30") will work without you telling it the format.

Comment: Perhaps, fix this one first,  `2012-02-31`?

Comment: `as.Date("2008-10-30", "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: @SimonWoodward, I added plain code in the body of the question you can just copy and paste to re-create the dataframe in R. Hopefully that makes it easier.

Comment: You might have loaded other packages than listed.   where is theme_gantt() from?

Comment: @Zhiqiang and Simon: R already recognizes both of those columns as Date with the format %Y-%m-%d. Why would I use the as.Date formula to cast/parse them as dates again?

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang sorry, that was just a typo in the StackOverflow editor, it's 2013-03-31 not 2012-02-31.

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang Interesting qusetion about theme_gantt()! I don't see it as an automatic theme included in tidyverse (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) - so maybe they somehow downloaded it in packages they have that I don't. Google doesn't seem to have anything anywhere about that theme. But the function annotate is where the error comes from, but theme_gantt() comes after annotate(), so it doesn't seem that would be relevant.

Comment: I am trying to help you work it out. At this stage, cannot reproduce your problem on my computer without it. Because `Error in theme_gantt() : could not find function "theme_gantt"`

Comment: You've been very helpful, thank you so much. Perhaps "comment out" "theme_gantt()" and see if it runs correctly or if that triggers the error? What version of ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: Alice you have as.Date() in your annotate()

Comment: Your date columns are strings, I think you will need to convert them to Date type before you can use them in scale_y_date and other ggplot functions.

Comment: Ok, the annotate function must be supplied with vectors of inputs (x,y,label), and these vectors must have the same length as the data (i.e. 9 rows). Would be better to use geom_text I think, put the annotations in your data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotate function must be supplied with vectors of inputs (x,y,label), and these vectors must have the same length as the data (i.e. 9 rows). Would be better to use geom_text I think, put the annotations in your data frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
library(extrafont)

csnp2008.sched.long <- structure(list(
        Component_ProgramItem = c("Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs","Citywide Programs", "Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Neighborhood Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks","Waterfront Parks"),
        task = c("Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule","Original Schedule","Updated Schedule"),
        ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18 = c("2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2016-01-27","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31","2019-12-31"),
        data.type = c("end", "end", "start", "start","end", "end", "start", "start","end", "end", "start", "start"),
        task.date = c("2012-08-30","2020-03-31","2008-08-28","2012-08-30","2013-03-31","2016-01-27","2008-08-28","2013-03-31","2015-02-28","2020-04-30","2008-08-28","2015-02-28")),
    .Names = c("Component_ProgramItem", "task", "ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18", "data.type", "task.date"),
    row.names = c(NA, 12L),
    class = "data.frame")

# convert strings to dates
csnp2008.sched.long <- csnp2008.sched.long %>%
    mutate(
        ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18 = as.Date(ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        task.date = as.Date(task.date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    )

#6 Create ggplot schedule
#order of "label=c("label name...", Label name 2...", ) is alphabetical
ggplot(csnp2008.sched.long, aes(x=task, y=task.date, colour=task)) +
    geom_line(size=70, show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#fadd9d", "#ffc000")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#fadd9d", "#ffc000")) +
    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
    scale_y_date(breaks = "1 year", date_minor_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y") +
    #guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL, reverse=TRUE)) +
    geom_hline(data = csnp2008.sched.long, aes(yintercept=ProjectedEndDate_6_30_18),
               color = "#7f7f7f", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
    # annotate("text",
    #        x=c("task","task","task"),
    #        y=as.Date(c("2008-10-30","2008-11-30","2008-12-30"), "%Y-%m-%d"),
    #        label=c("Citywide Programs",
    #               "Neighborhood Parks",
    #               "Waterfront Parks"),
    #        size = 3.75, hjust = "left", family = "Segoe UI Semilight") +
    #facet_grid(Component~., switch = "y", labeller = labeller(Component = label_wrap_gen(10))) +
    facet_grid(Component_ProgramItem~., switch = "y", scales = "free", space = "free") +
    # theme_gantt() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size = 9,
    #                                              family = "Segoe UI Semilight"),
    #                     axis.line.x = element_line(color= "#e7e5e6"),
    #                     axis.ticks.x = element_line (color = "#7f7f7f"),
    #                     axis.title=element_blank(),
    #                     axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    #                     strip.text = element_blank())+
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves it! Much, much appreciated.